# UITableView delete all rows at once

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uikit

How is it possible to delete all rows from UITableView at once?
Because when I reload table view with new data, I am still inserting new rows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
    }

    //... setting the new cell here ...

    return cell;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Remove all objects from array. Update tableView  and then add new data.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Do this.

Before you are reloading the table with

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Remove all objects from your tableView array (The array which populated your tableView)
For example.

```
[myArray removeAllObjects];
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: reloading table after removing objects is the key! thanks

Answer (score 7):

FYI, The solution above "Delete all of your dataSource, then call reloadData." sounds like they are advocating this:

```
TableView.dataSource = nil;
[TableView reloadData];
```

I tried that and it seemed to work.  Except, in iOS 8.1, I got random crashes.  And I do mean random, as in, I could execute that code 10x and it would crash 1x.  So, I used the recommended answer of:

```
[myArray removeAllObjects];
[tableView reloadData];
```

and now I am good.

Answer (score 4):

Delete all of your `dataSource`, then call `reloadData`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are not clearing your collection of data (`NSArray`) before your add more data. The `UITableView` will usually show all of your array data. If you don't want previous rows/data then you should empty your array prior to adding new information to it. Then call `[yourTableView reload]`

Answer (score 0):

first delete your old data

```
myArray = nil;
[tableView reloadData];
```

then load your new data

```
myArray = newData;
[tableView reloadData];
```